# How to frame a LPP from the following question

Tags: statistics, linear-programming

I'm starting to learn LP and I am unable to solve this effectively.
Can someone please help derive the decision variables, constraints and objective function for this problem so I can solve it?

```
Each machine costs $1500 per quarter and needs to be used for at least 2 quarters. 
Each machine can make 1000 tyres per month. 
The demand is 32000 for quarter 1, 
46000 for quarter 2, 
80000 for quarter 3, 
and 16600 for quarter 4. 
Inventory costs $5 per quarter per tyre, and inventory must be empty at the end of quarter 4.
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempt, it doesn't have to be correct. try to include your understanding of what is a decision variables, what are constraints, and the objective function.

Comment: The decision variables are $x_{ij}$:  Number of machines bought in quarter i and used in quarter $j$, where $j\geq i$

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.